# Draw lines on canvas in edit text but breaks on enter being pressed

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I have drawn lines in edit text like notepad through draw canvas. But when I press lots of enters and it goes out of view, then the canvas is drawn but doesn't draw lines and white spaces comes in edit text.

How can I draw these lines even after enter is pressed?